# Put dropdown selection menu to hide/show div in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, css

I need your help please... I want to put a drpdown menu in wordpress page... i put this code but i cant hide them.....

```html
<div id="AgwnistikesGR">
                        <h2 style="padding-left: 38%">Αγωνιστικές</h2>
      <select style="margin: 2% 0 3% 37.84%;" class="div-toggler" data-target=".Greekinfo">
          <option value="">Επιλέξτε αγωνιστική...</option>
<option value="agwn1" data-show=".agwn1">Αγωνιστική 1</option>
<option value="agwn2" data-show=".agwn2">Αγωνιστική 2</option>
<option value="agwn3" data-show=".agwn3">Αγωνιστική 3</option>
<option value="agwn4" data-show=".agwn4">Αγωνιστική 4</option>
<option value="agwn5" data-show=".agwn5">Αγωνιστική 5</option>
<option value="agwn6" data-show=".agwn6">Αγωνιστική 6</option>
<option value="agwn7" data-show=".agwn7">Αγωνιστική 7</option>
<option value="agwn8" data-show=".agwn8">Αγωνιστική 8</option>
<option value="agwn9" data-show=".agwn9">Αγωνιστική 9</option>
<option value="agwn10" data-show=".agwn10">Αγωνιστική 10</option>
<option value="agwn11" data-show=".agwn11">Αγωνιστική 11</option>
<option value="agwn12" data-show=".agwn12">Αγωνιστική 12</option>
<option value="agwn13" data-show=".agwn13">Αγωνιστική 13</option>
<option value="agwn14" data-show=".agwn14">Αγωνιστική 14</option>
<option value="agwn15" data-show=".agwn15">Αγωνιστική 15</option>
<option value="agwn16" data-show=".agwn16">Αγωνιστική 16</option>
<option value="agwn17" data-show=".agwn17">Αγωνιστική 17</option>
<option value="agwn18" data-show=".agwn18">Αγωνιστική 18</option>
<option value="agwn19" data-show=".agwn19">Αγωνιστική 19</option>
<option value="agwn20" data-show=".agwn20">Αγωνιστική 20</option>
<option value="agwn21" data-show=".agwn21">Αγωνιστική 21</option>
<option value="agwn22" data-show=".agwn22">Αγωνιστική 22</option>
<option value="agwn23" data-show=".agwn23">Αγωνιστική 23</option>
<option value="agwn24" data-show=".agwn24">Αγωνιστική 24</option>
<option value="agwn25" data-show=".agwn25">Αγωνιστική 25</option>
<option value="agwn26" data-show=".agwn26">Αγωνιστική 26</option>
<option value="agwn27" data-show=".agwn27">Αγωνιστική 27</option>
<option value="agwn28" data-show=".agwn28">Αγωνιστική 28</option>
<option value="agwn29" data-show=".agwn29">Αγωνιστική 29</option>
<option value="agwn30" data-show=".agwn30">Αγωνιστική 30</option>
     <div class="Greekinfo">
     <div class="agwn1">
   <table style="margin-top: 10%;" class="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
<tr>
    <th>Γηπεδούχος</th>
    <th>Φιλοξενούμενος</th>
    <th>Ημερομηνία</th>
    <th>Ώρα</th>
<th>TV</th>
</tr>
</thead>  
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>ΑΕΚ</td>
        <td>Παναιτωλικός</td>
        <td>00/00/00</td>
        <td>00:00</td>
        <td>Nova</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ΑΕΛ</td>
        <td>Βέροια</td>
        <td>00/00/00</td>
        <td>00:00</td>
        <td>Nova</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Α.Ο.Κέρκυρα</td>
        <td>Ατρόμητος Αθ.</td>
        <td>00/00/00</td>
        <td>00:00</td>
        <td>Nova</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ΑΕΠ Ηρακλής</td>
        <td>Α.Ο Ξάνθη</td>
        <td>00/00/00</td>
        <td>00:00</td>
        <td>Nova</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Λεβαδειακός</td>
        <td>ΠΑΟΚ</td>
        <td>00/00/00</td>
        <td>00:00</td>
        <td>Nova</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ολυμπιακός</td>
        <td>Αστέρας Τρίπολης</td>
        <td>00/00/00</td>
        <td>00:00</td>
        <td>Nova</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Πανιώνιος</td>
        <td>ΠΑΣ Γιάννινα</td>
        <td>00/00/00</td>
        <td>00:00</td>
        <td>Nova</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Πλατανιάς</td>
        <td>Παναθηναϊκός</td>
        <td>00/00/00</td>
        <td>00:00</td>
        <td>Nova</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I need something like that...

http://bettube.gr/tables/SuperLeague.php

Sorry my page is in Greek

Comment: What do you mean when you say "hide them" ? Is it the table or what?

Comment: Yes... U can click my url so u see exactly what i need... I want to make a sport site... i want my menu show the specific div depends on users option

Comment: Okay, but have you tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: Yes but this doesnt work.... I cant make it work on php site with my own code but when i put it in wordpress it doent work....you can scroll on wp site and see that my tables are not hide

Comment: If you have time i appreciate it if can take a look... THank you http://bettube.16mb.com/super-league/ my wordpress site                             and this is my my dropdown that works in php site http://bettube.gr/tables/SuperLeague.php